# In British English, is "in a restaurant" used when the place is important and "at a restaurant" used to talk about the purpose?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, british-english

As AmE speakers use *at* a restaurant when talking about the purpose of being there, but *in* a restaurant when the location matters to them, I was wondering if BrE speakers use "at" and "in" in the similar way as AmE speakers do.

For example:

- A: I have dinner at a restaurant every Saturday. Not "in a restaurant."
- B: "I was in a restaurant when it started to snow."
- C: "I was at a restaurant when it started to snow."

It would be wrong to think that "in" in B is used to talk about the purpose of being there, but it is possible to use "at" in B because I can choose to focus on the purpose of being in a restaurant or in other words by B with "in" I mean where I was when it started to snow and by C with "at" I express what I was doing, I was eating when it started to snow. Do BrE use them in the same way?

Comment: Why do you think there might be a difference? Did you see or hear British speakers using the language differently? Or have you done any research to see how British people talk about locations?

Comment: @gotube, Yes,  I was told by some native speakers there is a difference in use and it depends on dialects.

Comment: Well I'm British and the examples you give do not seem foreign to me. Though on something like this I would counsel against too much dogmatism. It is by no means impossible that I might say "I have dinner in a restaurant every Saturday".

Comment: And I wouldn't read much of anything into the difference between "I was at a restaurant when it started to snow" and "I was in a restaurant when it started to snow" (possibly not even the pedantic difference of being inside the building or simply upon the property).

Comment: @SoronelHaetir, can "in" be used when talking about the purpose? "I was in a restaurant when it started to snow" or would it be understood as as "where I was" by most native speakers? Because when native speakers say either can be used do they mean even if either can be used this doesn't mean that "in" can  express the purpose as "at" does and can be used instead of "at' to talk about the purpose of being in a particular place.

Comment: There is no difference in usage between _at [the]_ and _in [the]_ with _restaurant_ as there is with _school, church_ and _hospital_.